# pharmaceutical Affair act. Why someone put Affair in the middle of two words?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

I don't get it why pharmaceutical affair act used AFFAIR in the middle of phrase. Because without affair, it does make perfect sense. maybe there will be some reasons????????

Comment: It also makes perfect sense with the word, if you Google the phrase 'pharmaceutical affair act' and read what one of those is about, you can see that the word 'affair' fits just fine. That someone, who put the word there, was the legislator - and they might have had legal reasons to do so. To me 'pharmaceutical act' would either be an act brought by pharmacists or the one dealing with pharmaceuticals, which is more narrow than pharmaceutical affairs.

Comment: Are you asking about the Japanese law known in English as the [Pharmaceutical Affairs Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pharmaceutical_Affairs_Law_%28Japan%29) or Pharmaceutical Affairs Act? If so, you may be interested in Merriam-Webster's definitions 1(a) and 1(b) of the word _affair_: "**1  a** _pl[ural]_ : commercial, professional, public, or personal business **b :** MATTER, CONCERN." In short, the law's title refers to matters or concerns associated with the pharmaceutical industry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're referring to either Japan's Pharmaceutical Affairs Act[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pharmaceutical_Affairs_Law_(Japan)) or South Korea's Pharmaceutical Affairs Act[2](http://www.wipo.int/wipolex/en/details.jsp?id=2765). If not, please clarify which law you are referring to. Both of these back translate to "Affairs" not "Affair" which is correct English usage of the word to describe "transactions and other matters of professional or public business"[3](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/affairs)

Comment: Asking for clarification would be a better comment than an answer :-).

Comment: I should've known this site long ago so I can learn about english. Thank you !

Comment: Its unclear whether the "affairs" -> "affair" was caused by a misunderstanding of the law's title, a translation issue,  "affair" is itself a typo, or if the user doesn't understand that "affair" is a word to describe a law regulating the transaction of business operations.

Comment: I ruled out misunderstanding of the law title (in the original language) as the capitalization makes the spelling seem deliberate. I also ruled out "affair" being a typo for the same reason. This leaves bad translation and not understanding what the word "affairs" means in context.

Comment: Based on the way the question was asked, "to remove it makes more sense", it seems by far most likely to me that the user doesn't understand the context of "affair/affairs" in this context. The request for clarification in the question was to clarify context based on which law the OP is referring two but is not a required clarification to obtain a high probabilistic chance of the law in question being one of the two listed as they are the only two laws with the OP's title that ranked within the first couple pages of searching using both the affairs and affair search term.

Comment: @KimJay if the answer above is satisfactory to answer your question, please accept it.